# What does bit per color channel means?

Tags: image, image-processing

Determine the number of bytes necessary to store an uncompressed RGB color image of size 640 ×
480 pixels using 8, 10, 12, and 14 bits per color channel?
I know how to calculate the size of image by using Size = (rows * columns * bpp) but i cannot understand what bit per color channel means in this question

Comment: with 8 bits you can only have 2**8=256 different colors (say gray levels if only 1 channel). With 10 bits you can have 2**10=1024 different colors, which usually looks nicer, and so on

Comment: RGB color space has 3 channels: Red, Green and Blue. The "bits per color channel" is the number of bits that are used for storing each component (e.g 8 bits for red, 8 bits for green, 8 bits for blue). The dynamic range of 8 bits is [0, 255]. More bits applies larger range: 12 bits range is [0, 4095], and much larger colors variety can be coded in each pixel. The bits per channel is independent of memory storage (e.g. it's common to store 12 bit in 2 bytes [16 bits] in memory).

Comment: @Rotem please don't answer questions with comments. that's what answers are for...

Comment: @Piglet, specially for you I posted an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bits per color channel, is the number of bits that are used for storing a color component of a single pixel.

RGB color space has 3 channels: Red, Green and Blue.
The "bits per color channel" (**bpc**) is the number of bits that are used for storing each component (e.g 8 bits for red, 8 bits for green, 8 bits for blue).

The dynamic range of 8 bits is [0, 255] (255 = 2^8-1).
8 bpc applies 24 bits per pixel (**bpp**).
The number of bits per pixel defines the [Color Depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth) of the image.
24 bpp can represent 2^24 = 16,777,216 different colors.

More bits applies larger range: 12 bits range is [0, 4095] (4095 = 2^12-1), and much larger colors variety can be coded in each pixel.
12 bpc applies 36 bpp, and can represent 2^36 = 68,719,476,736 different colors.

For more information refer to [BIT DEPTH TUTORIAL](https://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/bit-depth.htm)

Remark: The bits per channel is not directly related to memory storage (e.g. it's common to store 12 bit in 2 bytes [16 bits] in memory).

As you probably know, an image is built as a matrix of pixels.
Following figure illustrates the structure of an RGB image:
[image: RGB image]

Following figure illustrates a pixel with 8 bits per color channel:
[image: 8 bits per color channel]

Following figure illustrates a pixel with 10 bits per color channel:
[image: 10 bits per color channel]

Following figure illustrates a pixel with 12 bits per color channel:
[image: 10 bits per color channel]

There subject is much wider than that, but I think that's enough...